# What encoding is this and how do I turn it into something I can see properly?

Tags: character-encoding

I'm writing a script that will operate on the subtitle files of a popular streaming service (Netfl*x).

The subtitle files have strange characters in them and I can't get them to render in a way that my text editors or web browser will display in a readable way. The xml encoding says UTF-8, but some characters are not readable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<tt xmlns:tt="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:ttm="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#metadata" xmlns:ttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#parameter" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" ttp:tickRate="10000000" ttp:timeBase="media" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml">
<p>de 15 % la nuit derniÃ¨re.</span></p>
<p>if youâve got things to doâ¦</span></p>
```

And in Vim:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the browser:

[image]
How can I convert this into something I can use?

Comment: 1. You are interpreting the file as UTF-8…?! 2. Look at it with a hex editor and tell us the exact bytes used, and what character you'd expect that to be.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb and say that file *is* UTF-8 encoded just fine, and you're merely looking at it using the wrong encoding. The character À encoded in UTF-8 is `C3 80`. `C3` in ISO-8859-1 is Ã, which in your screenshot is followed by an `80`. So looks like you're looking at a UTF-8 file using the (wrong) ISO-8859 encoding.

**Use the correct encoding when opening the file.**

Comment: The file "looks" this way even in the browser (see updated screenshot), which is where I got the information. Is the browser using the wrong encoding?

Comment: Maybe. Use *View → Encoding* to choose UTF-8; if that makes the file appear correctly, then the default encoding is simply wrong due to reasons which need to be discovered separately.

Comment: I don't have a view-> encoding option. Using Chrome... is this an option I need to enable?

Comment: Well, the equivalent must be *somewhere* in Chrome. Use a different browser, or open the file in a text editor where that’s definitely an option.

Answer (score 0):

My terminal is set to en_US.UTF-8, but was also rendering this supposedly UTF-8 encoded file incorrectly (sonné -> sonnÃ©). I was able to solve this by using `iconv` to encode the file in `ISO8859-1`.

`iconv original.xml -t ISO8859-1 -o converted.xml`

In the new file, the characters were properly rendered, although I don't quite understand why.